How to plot facet grid for different countries?
data <- data.frame(
  nuts = c("AT11", "AT11", "AT11", "AT12", "AT12", "AT12",
           "AT13", "AT13", "AT13", "AT21", "AT21", "AT21",
           "DE11", "DE11", "DE11", "DE12", "DE12", "DE12"),
  type = c("all", "flat", "house", "all", "flat", "house",
           "all", "flat", "house", "all", "flat", "house",
           "all", "flat", "house", "all", "flat", "house"),
  year = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007,
           2000, 2000, 2000, 2007, 2007, 2007,
           2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007))

I want to plot a facet grid. One grid for each country of interest. Suppose take austria. on the y axis there should be all nuts2 level code of austria and on x axis should be years for which the price data is available. i want horizontal bars. for each nuts2 code there should be three bars for three types of buildings. How can i do this with ggplot2? through the plot i want to show for which years data is available as this varies across countries. is there a better way of doing this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Data is a great step in the right direction, but the data you provided doesn't begin to represent the problem your having. It doesn't even make sense given the rest of your question. (What countries?) What have you tried in ggplot2 so far? If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.

Wait... your response variable (y) is categorical? How did you want to make a bar graph with no numbers?

Here's what I would do:
library(tidyverse)


# select only Austria NUTS regions
data <- data %>% filter(
  stringr::str_detect(nuts, "^AT")
)

# count the number of rows for each group
data <- data %>% 
  summarise(.by = c(nuts, type, year), n = n())
            
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = n)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = as.factor(year), fill = type), color = "white") +
  # set breaks on integers only
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.integer(unique(data$n))) +
  # create one facet foe each comnination od nuts and type
  facet_wrap(~interaction(nuts, type), ncol = 1)


Maybe this is what you are looking for:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data %>% 
  # Create a new 'country' variable
  mutate(country = gsub("[0-9]*", "", nuts),
         # Convert 'year' to a factor
         year = as.factor(year))

# Create a bar plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = nuts, y = year, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  # Create separate panels for each 'country' with free scales
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = "free")

